# Optimizing a threshold value on a dependent metric using a classifier trained to optimize a threshold-independent metric

Tags: classification, model-evaluation, hyperparameter, calibration, threshold

Is it a reasonable approach to train a probabilities classifier by optimizing a threshold-independent metric such as AUC, and then using the trained classifier to calibrate the decision threshold value on a train/validation (which used to choose the trained classifer's hyperparameters values)or both, to maximize a threshold-dependent metric like F1 score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a completely standard approach. (Although - rather than AUROC - folks would usually maximize a proper scoring rule such as the Brier score / mean squared error or log loss during training.)

In particular, the combination of log loss optimization on the training set + subsequent threshold selection (e.g. maximizing F1) on the validation set is probably the single most common approach.

So yes, without knowing any more details about your particular application, that sounds like a very reasonable approach.

Comment: I choose the model's hyperparameters that has the best auc score on a validation set, and then using the same val set for tuning the trained model's threshold value. Are you recommend to train the model just using the training set, and the using the validation set for tuning the threshold?

Comment: Using the val set for both hyperparameter tuning and threshold selection is fine. (In fact, the decision threshold *is* a hyper parameter.) A slightly better way might be to use cross-validation for hyper param (incl. threshold) selection instead of a single fixed pair of train/val set. See, e.g., [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/52632/105519). The only really important thing is to never do any model selection or parameter tuning whatsoever on the test set - unless you do *not* need an unbiased estimate of i.i.d. model performance.

Comment: Let:
$H$ are the model's set of hyperparameters (The threshold is not part of 
$H$). $AUC(M,H)$ is  model $M$  accuracy when using $H$ on a validation dataset.
First, we try to find $H^* = \arg\max_H AUC(M, H)$.When tuning the threshold, the problem is different and can be defined as: $t^* = \arg\max_{t} F1(M, H^*, t)$ 
where $F1(M, H^*, \text{t})$ represent the F1 score of model $M$ with hyperparameters $H^*$ when using the threshold value $\text{t}$ on a validation dataset. However, I assume from your answer that it is valid using the same validation set for the not identical problems.